# getText with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

The code worked back when I still used an EditText, but I changed it to an AutoCompleteTextView to make things easier for the user, and now I have a problem. Here is the bulk of the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    AutoCompleteTextView edit = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_item);

    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array);
    java.util.Arrays.sort(items);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    edit.setAdapter(adapter);

public void find(View view) {

    String name = edit.getText().toString();

    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Brown Turkey Fig")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BrownTurkeyFig.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Emerald Green Arborvitae")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmeraldGreenArborvitae.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Delaware Valley White Azalea")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DelawareValleyWhiteAzalea.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Ive included the parts that are related to the question. Basically, the user types the name of a plant in the AutoCompleteTextView, and then clicks a button to be brought to a new activity based on whatever plant they typed in (I included three as examples at the end). Before I added the autofill part, the code worked fine the way it was.

The problem is that when the button is clicked, the next activity is not brought up. It crashes the app.

I do not know what is wrong with it now. Perhaps I am not properly taking the actual text from the AutoCompleteTextView to be compared in my if statements? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a local variable "edit" in your oncreate method but also you are using a global variable in your "find" method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry , I can't understand what's your meaning. Maybe you can try to use `AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener`. For example:

```
edit.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = items.get(position);
                 if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("Brown Turkey Fig")){
                   Intent intent = new Intent(this, BrownTurkeyFig.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                 } else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("Emerald GreenArborvitae"){
                    Intent intent = new 
                               Intent(this,EmeraldGreenArborvitae.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 } else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("Delaware Valley White Azalea")){
                     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DelawareValleyWhiteAzalea.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
} 
            }
        })
```

Hope to help you.